# submitting simple form and capturing before and after screen

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

im trying to submit a simple form with phantomjs

here is my code

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    page.render("after_post.png");
    console.log("done2!" );
    phantom.exit();

};

page.open('http://localhost/bimeh/phantom/testhtml.php', function(status) {

    page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", function() {

        page.evaluate(function() {
           $("[name='xxx']").val('okk');
            page.render("pre_post.png");
            console.log('done1!');
            $('#subbtn').click();
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is i dont get the pre_post.png image her eis my output

```
$ phantomjs test.js
done2!
```

it seems onLoadFinished  is called before page.evaluate can do anything ... also in the after_post.png  i get picture of form before submit action

im using phantomjs 1.98 (i've downgraded from 2.1 becuz it want outputting errors apparently due to some bug in qt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    page.render("pre_post.png"); // <----
});
```

`page.evaluate` is as if you loaded a page in a browser and then run scripts in developer tools console. There is no variable `page` in there. `page` belongs to a PhantomJS level script:

```
page.open('http://localhost/bimeh/phantom/testhtml.php', function(status) {

    page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", function() {
        page.render("pre_post.png");

        page.evaluate(function() {
            $("[name='xxx']").val('okk');
            $('#subbtn').click();
        });
    });
});
```

`page.onLoadFinished` is called every time a page has finished loading: the first time PhantomJS opens the script and the second when form is submitted. You may keep your function as it is and in this case if form is submitted the first screenshot of original page will be overwritten with the second screenshot.

However most likely your form won't be submitted because buttons don't have a `click` method in PhantomJS, it was added in 2.x.

Your script also lacks a crusial thing: error control. Please use `page.onError` callback to catch any errors on the page (you may simply copy the function from here: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html )

Comment: thanx for the info , i had `page.onError` originally in my code but i took it out to make the code easier to read .... but i have to say it didnt catch any error ... also in the meantime i tried casperjs and it is so much easier to manage and read

Comment: CasperJS is also a good tool, but it uses PhantomJS underneath anyway and it is on its way out, I'm afraid. The new king of headless browsers is `puppeteer`, migrate now if you're only at the start of doing your headless work.