# Waiting for a selector after clicking the login button

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to login to a website using the following code.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://example.com/login/auth', function (status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            $('[name="email"]').val('username');
            $('[name="password"]').val('password');
            $('.btn-login').click(); // CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON
            // WHAT NEXT ??
            page.render('naluaa.png');
        });
    })
});
```

I have entered the username and the password, after including `jquery`. After entering the credentials, I click the login button. How should I wait for the authentication to succeed / or wait for the particular selector to load? (In this case, the page does not completely reload and a modal is popped up after the authentication succeeds) After the authentication has succeeded, I want to take a snapshot of the user-home page and then exit.

Currently, above code throws an error when it tries to run `page.render` the statement, saying that `page` is not defined. Do not really know the cause for it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214376/submitting-simple-form-and-capturing-before-and-after-screen/49220024#49220024

Comment: @Vaviloff Is there a way to wait for the selector? In my case page does not reload